# How to change windows 7 Home premium UI language?

Tags: windows, windows-7

I have windows 7 home premium whose default language is in spanish. i'm wondering how to change the default language to english.

any help will be appreciable.

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-the-display-language

Answer (score 1):

This can be  done after installing Multilingual User Interface (MUI) 
but Officially this can be only installed in Windows 7 ultimate or Enterprise edition,

Comment: can i change my language to english? i have windows 7 Home Premium

Comment: @Sujeet no you cant, until unless you have Windows 7 ultimate or enterprise edition

Comment: @Sujeet Don't forget to tick the answer, if you got correct information.
:)

Comment: is there any other way to do this or i have to buy ultimate or enterprise edition\?

Comment: @Sujeet ultimate is the best edition, go for it, or else, try to reinstall your home premium pack, and during installation check for language selection,
I am not sure for language selection option in home premium, but in ultimate it provides

Comment: Multi language is NOT available on Windows 7 Home premium.